# Datetime formula field is not getting updated

Tags: formula-field, datetime

I'm having two date time fields FieldA and FieldB and also I'm having a formula field which will hold either one of the two date time fields , if either is filled. But the value is not getting update. It still shows empty. Please find the formula I tried.

```
IF(
    FieldA!= null,
    FieldA ,
    IF(
        FieldB != null,
        FieldB,
        null
    )
)
```

Comment: Where does it being shown as empty? What are the values of fieldA and FieldB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ISBLANK() instead of checking for null.

Below or similar formula would do.

```
IF(ISBLANK( FieldA__c ), FieldB__c , FieldA__c )
```